# Conversion of phase noise unit from V^2/Hz to rad^2/Hz

Tags: signal-processing, phase-noise

I have been trying to measure the phase noise of an oscillator with a homodyne interferometric measurement with an I Q mixer in the microwave domain. The output I and Q are digitized. So, after calculating the Fourier transform, the PSD is in the unit of V^2/Hz.

Is there any way to convert this unit to rad^2/Hz? I have referred to Rubiola's [chart](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.07109.pdf). But I don't understand these conversion methods since, in this case, the carrier frequency is removed. Furthermore, I found [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=974236) reference, where the conversion is described by $$S_{\phi}(f) = (V_{\phi}(f)/K_{\phi})^2$$ where \$ K_{\phi} \$ is the phase detector constant in V/rad. And, \$ V_{\phi}(f) \$ is the equivalent phase noise measured in V^2/Hz. Is there a way to measure this phase detector constant of the digitizer, including the interferometric measurement setup? Or is there another method to convert the phase noise from V^2/Hz to rad^2/Hz? (what I have now is \$ V_{\phi}(f) \$).

I have tried different methods to convert it, but none of them seem to work, or maybe I am not able to find the right method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you compute atan(Q/I) (note: make sure you use atan2 here), you get the phase of your signal with respect to your reference phase (the reference you used to obtain I and Q). The spectrum of the arctangent is the phase noise. If you solely look at the spectrum of I*cos(wt)+jQ*sin(wt), you can obtain the SSB phase noise spectrum, which is an approximation of (half) the true phase noise spectrum assuming the phase deviations are small and amplitude noise is negligible.

Comment: Also strictly speaking, SSB phase noise is specified in dBc/Hz. What you seem to be looking for specifically is the spectral density of the phase noise itself, which is in rad^2/Hz. That is, if we have a signal v=Acos(wt+phi), the SSB phase noise is the spectral density of skirts around v with respect to the total power in v (units dBc/Hz). The true phase noise is the spectral density of phi, in rad^2/Hz. If you do a Taylor series expansion of v around phi=0, you can show the relation between the two: SSB phase noise is 3dB smaller than the true spectral density of phi.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. @LetterSized. I was wondering; if I have the voltage equivalent of the phase noise power spectral density in the unit of V^2/Hz. Can I convert to rad^2/Hz using the phase detector constant K_phi? Is this factor the phase to the voltage gain of the mixer? If yes, may I please know how to measure this?

Comment: It's not clear to me how exactly you are doing the phase detection. But if you truly have a phase detector, then you should multiply by K_phi^2 to go between V^2/Hz and rad^2/Hz. This of course assumes K_phi is in units of rad/V. To answer your final question, it would be helpful to have a block diagram of your measurement, just to make sure we're on the same page about how exactly you are doing the phase detection.